# Switch default http error messages from HTML to plaintext in Adonis

Tags: adonis.js

By default, Adonis generates "nicely formatted" error responses. Problem is, they often generate more pain than they help. It turns hard to read responses in the console or tools like Postman. How can I configure so that Adonis always responds in plaintext in case of an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in AdonisJS project directory

```
adonis make:ehandler
```

File *app\Exceptions\Handler.js* will be created. Now you will get simple errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your global error handler, you can set the headers to plain text like this:

```
response.header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
```

Comment: could you please specify the file where that configuration is contained? Or do I have to create that configuration file? I can't find a global error handler in the documentation